# How to configure config in codeigniter when shifting directory from one server to another

Tags: php, codeigniter

I shifted my web directory from one hosting server to other hosting server and configured database name, user, password correctly.. showing following error when run it

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

modify database config file, you just have to change driver, as `mysql_*` functions which are now deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future.

```
<site_folder>/application/config/database.php
```

Modify

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

**TO**

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

**OR**

- php mysqli is not installed.
- extension is disabled.

Comment: @Asad reason could be old server had old version of PHP, `mysql_*` functions has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7

Comment: still not working.. this is database file code

`$db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'user',
 'password' => 'password',
 'database' => 'db_name',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => FALSE,
 'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);`

Comment: @Asad: OS ? did you check php.ini extension is installed ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the CI [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=database#database-drivers-mysql-sqlite-mssql-pdo-dblib):

> The mysql driver utilizes the old ‘mysql’ PHP extension, known for its
>   aging code base and many low-level problems. The extension is
>   deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and CodeIgniter deprecates it in version 3.0,
>   switching the default configured MySQL driver to mysqli.
>
> Please use either the ‘mysqli’ or ‘pdo/mysql’ drivers for MySQL. The
>   old ‘mysql’ driver will be removed at some point in the future.
>
> The sqlite, mssql and pdo/dblib (also known as pdo/mssql or
>   pdo/sybase) drivers all depend on PHP extensions that for different
>   reasons no longer exist since PHP 5.3.
>
> Therefore we are now deprecating these drivers as we will have to
>   remove them in one of the next CodeIgniter versions. You should use
>   the more advanced, sqlite3, sqlsrv or pdo/sqlsrv drivers respectively.

Secondly, PHP itself has removed `mysql` since PHP 7 as per the release [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php).

Comment: thanks for responding.. but even `mysqli` is not working in my case.. I shared database file data in another answer below kindly check it